# How To Select default value in dropdown

Tags: asp.net

While updating location details i want to fill all the input fields with my database values

```
1) $("#drdState").find('option[value='+ ID_State +']').attr('selected', 'selected');

2) $("#drdState > [value=" + ID_State + "]").attr("selected", "true");
```

I have tried above 2 lines code but still i am not able to set state name as selected in dropdown.

Comment: What is the reason behind selecting the default value using javascript / jquery instead of the code behind? What I would do is: Just after filling your dropdown, then select the `SelectedValue` property of your dropdown.

Comment: Is it an ASP Dropdownlist?

Comment: This question is a little ambiguous. Please provide more details. https://stackoverflow.com/help  

The markup for the select list itself, and the code that is retrieving the data would be immensely helpful.